# passing parameter to another method in python webpy

Tags: python, web.py

i am trying to pass the parameter to another method and i am getting an exception.

```
import web
import json

class Process:
    def request(self, query_string):
        print query_string
    def GET(self):
        params  = web.input()
        request(params)
        return json.dumps(dict(foo=55))
```

This gives me.

```
<type 'exceptions.NameError'> at /process
global name 'request' is not defined
```

Can any one explain why i cannot pass the variable to another method.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the fact that 'request' method is not receiving 'self' as first parameter? Actually, it is receiving 'self', but not the query_string as intended. Shouldn't it be def request(self, query_string) instead?

Comment: I tried both self as first parameter too

Comment: is it still the same error with self as first parameter?
also, why is the method defined as request, and called as do_request ?
have you tried it to call it with self.request(params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace   `request(params)` with  `self.request(params)`

All relations have to be explicitly stated in python. It's not like C++ or Java where class functions are automatically visible to one another. You have to explicitly reference self to access them.